# Save output of method in variable instead of file in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to store an output file of a method in a variable instead of a file?
I want to use the method:

```r
decode("base64.txt", "output.tif")
```

But instead of writing the output in "output.tif", I want to store it in a variable to plot it:

```r
# Something like this
output <- decode("base64.txt", "output.tif")
plotRGB(output, b=3, g=2, r=1, stretch="lin")
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: in which package is the `decode` function you are trying to use?

Comment: The name is base64

Answer (score 1):

You could use a raw connection to get the data

```
rawcon <- rawConnection(raw(), "w")
base64::decode("base64.txt", rawcon)
output <- rawConnectionValue(rawcon)
close(rawcon)
output
```

You could also use a different package for base64 encoding like `openssl`

```
buf <- readBin("base64.txt", raw(), file.info("base64.txt")$size)
output <- openssl::base64_decode(buf)
```

Comment: Can I also just pass a string as a parameter, when the method needs a txt file? So can I imitate a txt file with a string? So that i dont need the base.txt file.

Comment: You could fake it with `base54` by using another raw connection, but it really would be better to use `openssl` functions which don't need the data written to disk.